# How set RRD to store for 2 years?

Tags: database, linux, rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

I'm monitoring more than 300 servers, for that I'm using [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/).
Which use `RRD` as database to collect and store data related the resources of each server.
I would like to have a history about 2 years or more, so reading this [article](http://www.cuddletech.com/articles/rrd/ar01s02.html), I think that my `RRA` configuration should be :

```
RRAs "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:17520"
```

17520 = (365 days [year] x 2) * 24 [hour]

This is Ganglia default configuration, which is running today:

```
#
# Round-Robin Archives
# You can specify custom Round-Robin archives here (defaults are listed below)
#
# RRAs "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:244" "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:24:244" "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:168:244" "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:672:244" \
#      "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:5760:374"
#
```

Is that right my way of thinking or I'm missing something here ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After studying this subject for a while, I came up with an answer that may help someone in the future.  I read these two articles many times, which I recommend.
Read this one first, [Creating an initial RRD](http://www.cuddletech.com/articles/rrd/ar01s02.html) then read this one. [How to create an RRDTool database](http://apfelboymchen.homeunix.net/gnu/rrd/create/):

I will try to explain it simply.  Format `RRA:CF:xff:steps:rows`:

```
RRA: Round Robin Archive
CF: Consolidation Factor
XFF: Xfile Factor
steps
rows
```

The biggest issue for me was to discover the right value for `steps` and `rows`. 
After reading, I came up with this explanation:

```
1 day - 5-minute resolution
1 week - 15-minute resolution
1 month - 1-hour resolution
1 year - 6-hour resolution

RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:288 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:3:672 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:744 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:72:1480
```

Keep in mind that our `step` is `300 seconds`, so the idea is very simple:
If I want to resolve `one day` which has `86400 seconds`, as shown in the first example, how many rows do I need? The answer is `288 rows`.  Why?

```
`86400 seconds [1 day] / 300 seconds [5 minutes`] = 288 rows
```

Another example, if I want to resolve: 
1 week `[ = 604800 seconds ]` in 15 minutes `[ = 900 seconds ]` = 604800/900 = `672 rows`

And so it goes on for the other values.  This way you are going to find out how many `rows` you need.
Finding out how many `steps` you need is very simple, you just have to take the multiplier of your steps.

Let me explain:  Our `steps` are `300 seconds`, right?

So if we want to resolve 5 minutes `[ = 300 seconds ]`, we just need to multiply by 1, right?
So, 15 minutes means by 300 seconds x 3, 1 hour means 300 x 12, 6 hours mean 300 x 72 and so on.

In my specific case, I would like to my `steps` be `30 seconds`, so I came up with these structure:

```
1   every time           30 seconds      1 * 30s = 30s
2   every second time     1 minute       2 * 30s = 1m
4   every third time      2 minutes      4 * 30s = 2m
10  every 10th time       5 minutes     10 * 30s = 5m
20  every 20th time      10 minutes     20 * 30s = 10m
60  every 60th time      30 minutes     60 * 30s = 30m
80  every 80th time      40 minutes     80 * 30s = 40m
100 every 100th time     50 minutes    100 * 30s = 50m
120 every 120th time      1 hour       120 * 30s = 1h
240 every 240th time      2 hours      240 * 30s = 2h
360 every 360th time      3 hours      360 * 30s = 3h

RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:120 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:2:120 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:4:120 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:10:288 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:20:1008 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:60:1440 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:80:3240 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:100:5184 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:120:8760 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:240:8760 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:360:8760 \
```

Which means:

```
1 hour    -  30 seconds  resolution
2 hours   -  1 minute    resolution
4 hours   -  2 minutes   resolution
1 day     -  5 minutes   resolution
1 week    - 10 minutes   resolution
1 month   - 30 minutes   resolution
3 months  - 40 minutes   resolution
6 months  - 50 minutes   resolution
1 year    -  1 hour      resolution
2 year    -  2 hour      resolution
3 year    -  3 hour      resolution
```

Well, I hope this helps someone, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for this; this information helped me to start collecting decade long metrics. I documented the whole process for Centos 7, for which you need to build a newer rrdtool: https://onnonymous.wordpress.com/2017/06/22/keeping-ganglia-graphs-longer-than-one-year/